# Domain Url work but Post-Url 'not found' Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ftp, url

I just installed Apache, MySQL, PHP, and phpMyAdmin in aws-EC2 virtual server. I've configured everything else. I also successfully installed a web script and my site is online. but when I visit my site post URL getring the error "not found" like this www.mywebsite.com/this-is-the-url, Only ip & domain url working. when I open any URL post it not work (but site.com/admin panel work ).. screenshot: http://prntscr.com/7x11sk

Also sometimes getting error when upload to var/www/ by ftp "file transfer failed" and "No such file or directory" & "Permission denied" when change any file permission from filezilla. I spent 5hours to correct & searching web but no any one result helped & nothing happens. anyone can help What I to do correct that will work fine.

Ftp screen shot: http://prntscr.com/7x11e3

you can check to visit my ip 54.169.236.106 & admin by /admin

Comment: What do the Apache logs contain on the requests producing the error?